# Highcharts column width on a time series axis

Tags: highcharts

I'm plotting columns in a chart with a time series x axis. This works well, but I'd like each column to have a meaningful width, e.g. 1 hour, not x pixels. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way would be to calculate the width in pixels based on the number of hours in your series, and the size of the x-axis in pixels.

You can translated axis values to pixel values using the toPixels function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels()

Using this, and getExtremes(), you can calculae the pixel valus of the start and end points of the xAxis.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I'll just use a step chart instead; looks similar, and is less trouble.